# Counting number of rows that follow unique combinations of columns values in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, apache-zeppelin

I'm working on Apache Zeppelin.
I have the following table:

```
|address | metric1 | metric2 | metric3|
|--------|---------|---------|--------|
|v       |        1|       1 |     200|
|w       |        1|       0 |     200|
|x       |        0|       1 |     200|
|y       |        0|       1 |     200|
|z       |        1|       0 |       1|
```

I want to create a query that shows all the possible combinations of metrics values with a count of how many adresses ended with each combination.

Like this:

```
| metric1 | metric2 | metric3| count|
|---------|---------|--------|------|
|        1|       1 |     200|     1|
|        1|       0 |     200|     1|
|        0|       1 |     200|     2|
|        1|       0 |       1|     1|
```

I tried the following query:

```
select metric1, metric2, metric3, count(*) as cnt 
from
(select distinct metric1, metric2, metric3 from table) as t;
```

but it results in this error:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Expression not in GROUP BY key 'metric1'

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need `GROUP BY`:

```
select metric1, metric2, metric3, count(*) as cnt 
from t
group by metric1, metric2, metric3;
```

A subquery is not needed.